# Reinitializing a storyboard embedded mapview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I've created an MKMapview in the storyboard. But then in the viewDidDisappear method of the .m file of the view controller I deleted the storyboard-created mapview by doing this:

```
    self.mapView.delegate = nil; 
    [self.mapView removeFromSuperview]; 
    self.mapView = nil;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to reinitialize the mapview to the way it's initialized through the storyboard. Is my only option to use the initWithFrame: way?

Comment: Why did you do that?  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup—short of reloading the whole storyboard, there isn’t a way to get any of its contents reinitialized. Is there a reason you’re removing the map view from its superview? Clearing the delegate should be enough to prevent it causing unexpected effects while offscreen.

Comment: There have been many instances of the mapview using up a lot of memory, even when you segue out. The solution, as of now, is to do what I did. So I guess I just have to do everything programmatically then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always initialize your MKMapView programmatically:

`self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:…];`

and add its delegate programmatically:

`self.mapView.delegate = self;`

and add it to a view:

`[self.view addSubview:self.mapView]`